# how to implement postgresql replication in django?

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

I am having some challenge implementing database replication in django using postgresql. I followed the instruction on this page https://github.com/yandex/django_replicated/tree/master/django_replicated but i keep getting the error.

'ReplicationMiddleware' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

The [`Middleware` class in that library](https://github.com/yandex/django_replicated/blob/master/django_replicated/middleware.py) is using the "old" style middleware from Django < 1.10.

You can see [the note on the changes in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/):

> A new style of middleware was introduced for use with the new MIDDLEWARE setting. If you’re using the old MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting, you’ll need to adapt old, custom middleware before using the new setting. This document describes new-style middleware. Refer to this page in older versions of the documentation for a description of how old-style middleware works.

It will need [to be adapted for use with Django >= 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Its true am using django 1.10 but I have not written a middleware class before. It looks like some real work.

Comment: You just need to adapt it for the new style, not rewrite it

Comment: I will try it but for now, i downgraded to django 1.9 and it resolved the issue. However, the database is used as 'slave' does not have any record. Hence, the replication is not working as i intend using the master database for writing and the slave for reading.